# Parent/Child table design?

Tags: database-design

Lets say I have a table to hold `Tasks` and then I have a table to hold `Sub Tasks`, is it better to break `Tasks` and `Sub Tasks` into separate tables or keep them both in the same table with a possible `ParentId` column.  What if a `Parent Task` could also be a `Sub Task`, does this change the design?

Comment: Are the columns the same for Tasks and SubTasks?  If so, then store them in one table with an ParentID / ChildID relationship.

Comment: My answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51901/10832 may help you with design.

Comment: @MaxVernon - Yes the columns are the same for both

Answer (score 3):

If a Parent Task and Subtask are essentially identical, save their rank in a hierarchy, then yes, a single table is appropriate. You can use a nullable foreign key to the primary key in the same table like this:

```
create table tasks (
  task_id bigserial primary key,
  subject text,
  ...,
  parent_task_id bigint null references tasks(task_id)
);
```

If your database server does [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) (example PostgreSQL), then use those for querying. Here are [some examples](http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/02/trees-paths-recursive-cte-postgresql.html).